# asp.net background server process to generate ssrs rldc pdfs and then email

Tags: asp.net, email, reporting-services, background, webforms

We have a "monthly" requirement to have a user select a few customers from a grid and press the "Process" button where a set of reports are to be generated as PDFs and then emailed to a set of people for each customer.  Each person would get a different set of reports based on location.  Of course, the SQL-SRVR database has all of the email addresses and the set of reports needed by customer and by person.

For ad-hoc view of the report(s), we have a reports dashboard page that allows user to select a report and parameters and launch into a new page that uses SSRS rdlc files that use ObjectDataSource(s) with appropriate parameters to feed into the ReportViewer for viewing.  PDFs can be generated by code or by user-menu choice from the ReportViewer menu-bar.  This works ok to generate and email a single report based on user-selected options.

For the "monthly" process, the parameters and reports are coming from the DB for each customer and person.  We would like to set off a process for the few selected customers that would execute on the server so that the user is not detained from additional action with the application.  Also the time to generate these reports (for example) may take 30 minutes.

So, my questions...How do I spawn a detached server process and pass the few data elements to the process?

If the user "logs-out" and closes the web-application, does the detached process continue to run?

Can a detached server process make use of the ReportViewer web-control and ObjectDataSource-controls and DB to generate the PDFs at the server?

Can the detached server process email the PDFs to the persons?

How will I know when the process is finished?  User may have closed the page that starts this monthly process.

Any other advice to solve this?

Comment: Hi, So the monthly process doesn't have any intervention with the users?

Comment: Thx for reply. Well, we are trying to understand our capabilities with the detached thread (I read up more about this).  It would be nice to get UI feedback of the progress (custName, personName...) a separate page (in a new tab), but we do not know if this is possible. For now in this post, can we learn from the questions asked at this beginning stage of finding a solution.  I want to use the ReportViewer capabilities to generate the PDF reports since it is very easy to code, and we already know how to send emails, but are not sure these components can be executed in a detached server thread.